# Can not call helper magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: extensions, helper, ce-1.9.2.2

I can not call helper:

My helper file: class Test_Productvideo_Helper_Video extends

Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract

Call helper on methode in controller file:

$video = Mage::helper('productvideo/video')->getVideoByUrl($url);

But $video return null.

Help me fix it!

Comment: show the code <helpers></helpers> code from the config.xml of this module

Comment: <helpers>
            <productvideo>
                <class>Test_Productvideo_Helper</class>
            </productvideo>
        </helpers>

Comment: Check error log in var directory. if there is any error put it here

Comment: $files = scandir(dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_));  <p> Warning: scandir() has been disabled for security reasons  in /home/wwwroot/www.abctest.com/includes/src/Test_Productvideo_Helper_Video.php

Comment: `Remove the scandir string from the disable_functions at php.ini* file` or
`Ask your hosting provider to remove the string above if you don't have an access to the php.ini* file`